# Django get a queryset and filter by own queryset item

Tags: django, django-views

first of all, I cant find the way to explain what I'm intend to do properly so I'll try to do it the best way I can, hope it make sense to you.

I'm trying to display on my index page a list of items that meet a certain criteria. I am creating an inventory app and I want to get a list of all items that need to be resupplied.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    template_name = 'inventario/index.html'
    model = Item

    # GETS ALL ALCTIVE ITEMS
    articulos = Item.objects.all().filter(activo=True)

    for i in articulos:
        # PRINTS THE VALUE OF 'cantidad_existente' AND 'cantidad_minima' ON EACH ITERATION 
        print(F'--->>>>>>{i.cantidad_existente}<<<<<<<---CANTIDAD EXISTENTE')
        print(F'--->>>>>>{i.cantidad_minima}<<<<<<<---CANTIDAD MINIMA')

        # TRIES TO GET FILTERD VALUE  FOR EACH ITEM 
        articulo =  Item.objects.filter(cantidad_existente__lte=i.cantidad_minima)


        print(F'--->>>>>>{articulo}<<<<<<<---')

    # print(F'--->>>>>>{articulo}<<<<<<<---')

    return render(request, template_name)#, {'items': items})
```

**results in terminal**

```
--->>>>>>6<<<<<<<---CANTIDAD EXISTENTE
--->>>>>>20<<<<<<<---CANTIDAD MINIMA
--->>>>>><QuerySet [<Item: Rondana 1/8>, <Item: Cortador Carburo 1/8>]><<<<<<<---
--->>>>>>2<<<<<<<---CANTIDAD EXISTENTE
--->>>>>>5<<<<<<<---CANTIDAD MINIMA
--->>>>>><QuerySet [<Item: Cortador Carburo 1/8>]><<<<<<<---
```

So I can see that every iteration brings back cantidad_minima and  cantidad_existente for each item in the queryset. My reasoning is that every iteration it would query my database bring back my result i wanted but its not. what am i doing wrong and how can i go about this issue

**UPDATE:**

I have made some changes to my query and now its working the way I wanted to (sorts of).

**updated function on views.py**

```
def index(request):
    template_name = 'inventario/index.html'
    model = Item

    # GETS ALL ALCTIVE ITEMS
    articulos = Item.objects.all().filter(activo=True)
    l = []
    for i in articulos:
        # PRINTS THE VALUE OF 'cantidad_existente' AND 'cantidad_minima' ON EACH ITERATION 
        print(F'--->>>>>>{i.cantidad_existente}<<<<<<<---CANTIDAD EXISTENTE')
        print(F'--->>>>>>{i.cantidad_minima}<<<<<<<---CANTIDAD MINIMA')

        # TRIES TO GET FILTERD VALUE  FOR EACH ITEM 
        articulo =  Item.objects.filter(cantidad_existente__lte=i.cantidad_minima).filter(pk=i.pk)
        if articulo:
            l.append(articulo)

        print(F'--->>>>>>{articulo}<<<<<<<---')

    print(F'--->>>>>>{l}<<<<<<<---')

    return render(request, template_name, {'items': l})
```

now the problem I have is how to display the elements on my template, how can I iterate over a list to get an item in a queryset?

**results in terminal**

```
--->>>>>>21<<<<<<<---CANTIDAD EXISTENTE
--->>>>>>20<<<<<<<---CANTIDAD MINIMA
--->>>>>><QuerySet []><<<<<<<---
--->>>>>>4<<<<<<<---CANTIDAD EXISTENTE
--->>>>>>5<<<<<<<---CANTIDAD MINIMA
--->>>>>><QuerySet [<Item: Cortador Carburo 1/8>]><<<<<<<---
```

**UPDAtE 2:** Adding models

I'm using **Item** that has  all common field to all tools in my inventory and this class gets inherited by other classes that have field unique to a specific tool.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
    numero_parte = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad_existente = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    update = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    cantidad_minima = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    precio_unitario = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    # asignado_a = models.ForeignKey(Empleados, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    anaquel = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ANAQUEL, blank=True, null=True)
    posicion_en_x = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    posicion_en_y = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.total = self.cantidad_existente * self.precio_unitario
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description 


class Cortadores(Item):
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipos_Cortadores,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Materiales, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    filos = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GABILANES)
    diametro = models.ForeignKey(Diametros, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    longitud = models.ForeignKey(Longitud, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desbaste = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DESBASTE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cortadores"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inventario:cortadores-list', kwargs={'id': self.tipo.id})

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (  str(self.tipo), str(self.material), str(self.filos), str(self.diametro), 
                                        self.longitud, self.desbaste
                                        )
```

**index.html**

```
{% block lista %}
    <div class="container cf">
        <div class="lista">
            {% if items %}
            <table id="tablas" class="cf">
                <tr class="theader">
                    <th>Tipo</th>
                    <th>Descripcion </th>
                    <th>No. Parte</th>
                    <th>Proveedor</th>
                    <th>C. Existente</th>
                    <th>C. Minima </th>
                    <th>Locaci&oacute;n</th>

                </tr>

                {% for c  in items %}
                    <tr class="list-index" >
                        <td>{{c.cortadores.tipo.c}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.numero_parte}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.proveedor}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.cantidad_existente}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.cantidad_minima}}</td>
                        <td>Anaquel: {{c.anaquel}} | {{c.posicion_en_x}} | {{c.posicion_en_y}}</td>
                    </tr>

                {% endfor%}
            </table>

            {% else %}

                <h1>No hay articulos por vencer</h1>
            {%endif%}

        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock lista%}
```

[image]

Comment: show your models?

Comment: @HemanthSP. Done I've updated my post to show my model

Comment: your template code is fine,please highlight your question

Comment: Well basically it now changed to a display issue, I'm able to get the right amount of values depending on the filter  but cant seem to display them now  on my page, my site generated the row for every element that gets sent by the context dictionary but cant display data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

## GETS ALL ALCTIVE ITEMS

```
articulos = Item.objects.all().filter(activo=True,)
l = []
for i in articulos:


    # TRIES TO GET FILTERD VALUE  FOR EACH ITEM 
    articulo =  Item.objects.filter(pk=i.pk,cantidad_existente__lte=i.cantidad_minima)
    if articulo:
        l.append(articulo[0])


return render(request, template_name, {'items': l})
```

Comment: try to workon your query it is not good, and it is very hard understand your logics,may be gives worng results

Comment: sure thing! will try to optimize it, any suggestions on what should i be looking for. I'm relatively new to  MYSQL, Django, python in general. even if  I now have  over a year  trying to learn programming it has been a very  sporadically  process (some times cant find time to study or practice ) its mainly in my spare time hobbies

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending your list as context, so you can just iterate over the list in your template

```
{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.0 }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.1 }}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If that doesn't work try adding the field names after the index like `{{ item.0.description }}`

Comment: this is what i currently have      
              `{% for c  in items %}
      <tr class="list-index" >
       <td>{{c.cortadores.tipo.c}}</td>
       <td>{{c.description}}</td>
       <td>{{c.numero_parte}}</td>
       <td>{{c.proveedor}}</td>
       <td>{{c.cantidad_existente}}</td>
       <td>{{c.cantidad_minima}}</td>
       <td>Anaquel: {{c.anaquel}} | {{c.posicion_en_x}} | {{c.posicion_en_y}}</td>
      </tr>

     {% endfor%}`

Comment: In my page I'm able to see the table row generated but is has empty values,  I also have tried with  the "." (as if it was an object. tr transverse object nested inside and object) and also tried indexing  with no succes

Comment: I think its because you are appending the queryset to list. Try the edits in my answer

Comment: ok now  i got a bit confused should i remove the for cycle?   I'm going to get error on the second filter  `.filter(cantidad_existente__lte=i.cantidad_minima)`  I'm not longer iterating so the "i" will crash my function, and second concern is how will i get the values from cantidad minima as a int (for the condition to work)?

Comment: oh I see the i now. Keep what you originally have in the view if it is working and try just using indexes in the template. I'll update my answer for an example

Comment: Is there anyway I could do this without using a list? I tried your suggestion for my template and apparently  the list is not a list of query sets it only has one value per index . I need to find a way to pass all fileds of the queryset

Comment: Yea I would try to avoid using a list and just return a queryset. If you could describe in words what you are trying to do to the queryset that would be helpful

Comment: well I'm only trying to display in my homepage a list of items that are near depleted  and that need to be replaced. I'm not trying to make any changes to the data it self only filter the correct data. since this is my homepage I have no pk  or id I can pass in my url to filter every item by it, so i need to find a way to get the value  that I will use to evaluate for every item so I can filter out this way. does that sound logical to you ??

Comment: **leelum**  Thanks a lot! as  @Hemanth SP suggested  changing the way i appended the element to the list  made things work!

Comment: Ok great, don't forget to accept his answer if its works for you

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. you are awesome !

Comment: logic is very difficult to understand